# Bash Script Put Text at the Beginning of all Files if Conditions are Met

Tags: shell-script, grep

I'm trying to write a bash script to put text at the beginning of all files in all subdirectories only if:

1. The file does not contain that text
2. The file contains the company's name, the word River, or the word Systems

Here's what I have so far:

```
for i in $(find -name *.cpp -type f -print)
do 
if ! grep -r 'This document contains technical data' $i && grep -r 'company name' $1 || grep-r 'River' $i || grep -r 'Systems' $i; then
#add text
```

Right now, the file that does not contain any keywords is not getting altered (as expected), but for files that have the text already and the keywords, they get altered.
I tried using [] around the || statements, but the result was the same. Any suggestions?

Comment: Looks like a typo in `grep-r 'River' $i` (missing a space between `grep` and `-r`)

Answer (score 3):

```
find . -name '*.cpp' -type f \
  ! -exec grep -qF 'This document contains technical data' {} ';' \
  -exec grep -qFe River -e 'company name' -e Systems {} ';' \
  -exec sed -i '1i\
This document contains technical data' {} +
```

(replace `sed -i` with `sed -i ''` with FreeBSD/macos' `sed`)

Or more efficiently with GNU `grep` and GNU `xargs`:

```
grep --include='*.cpp' -rFlZ -e River -e 'company name' -e Systems . |
  xargs -r0 grep -FLZ 'This document contains technical data' |
  xargs -r0 sed -i '1i\
This document contains technical data.'
```

Some notes about your attempts:

- [`find -print`'s output cannot be post-processed](/q/321697).
- [parameter expansions must be quoted in `bash`](/q/68694)
- `-r` (a GNU extension), is for *recursive* grep, for `grep` to do `find`'s job in addition to its own job, you'd only want to use it when `grep`ping directories (for it to find files in them, and then find the pattern in those files).
- `*` is a special character to the *shell*, it triggers globbing there. You should make sure it's quoted so a literal `*.cpp` be passed to `find`.
- if you want to check whether a pattern can be matched in a file, without needing to see all the lines where it's matched, use the `-q` option. Not only does it skip the printing, but it's also more efficient as `grep` stops looking at the first match. `-l` and `-L` (a GNU extension) have the same optimisation. The former prints the path of the file if the pattern is found and the latter if it's not found.
- to search for `F`ixed strings (as opposed to do regular expression matching), use the `-F` option, then you don't need to escape regular expression operators.
- no need to do `grep foo file || grep bar file` (or with `find`, `'(' -exec grep -q foo {} ';' -o -exec grep -q bar {} ';' ')'`), `grep` can find several pattern in a *or* fashion in one go with `grep -e foo -e bar file` or [other approaches](/a/695993).
- note that `grep -F River` also matches in `Riverside` or `WindRiver`. You can add the `-w` option to match only *whole* words (where words have to be delimited by non-word characters, word characters being alnums or underscores and non-words anything else).

Answer (score 2):

This worked once I replaced the && with another if statement:

```
if ! grep -r 'This document contains technical data' $i; then
  if grep -r 'company name' $1 || grep-r 'River' $i || grep -r 'Systems' $i; then
     #add text
  fi
fi
```